# How do I add a partitioned row number to Azure Data factory?

Tags: sql, azure-data-factory

Lets say the Schema is

```
{
ProductID INT
ProductVersion string
ProductVersionLaunchDate datetime
}
```

And I am trying to get a result of just the most recent product version for each product.

Normally in SQL I would do:

```
Select 
Row_Number() Over (Partition by ProductID order by ProductVersionLaunchDate desc) as RankOrder
```

to get a row number that resets on each ProductID, and then select each record with a 1 in the RankOrder column.

I know that Azure Data Factory has a row number function but when using it I didnt see a way to partition and was only able to get an incremental number increase across the whole data set. Does ADF have a work around for this or should I find a way to do this outside of ADF?

Answer (score 0):

Add a Window transformation and set the "Over" column to ProductID and Sort to ProductVersionLaunchDate descending. Then use the formula rowNumber() in the Window Column expression.